# How do you change the size of the a drop down arrow for the spinner in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to change the size and not the image or background color. I can't find any examples of changing the size of it.

Comment: What do you mean by size ? Height and Width ?

Comment: Yeah! , I don't see any examples of this. I'm using the material light drop down style.. usually when i hold command and click on the theme it shows me the code, but now when i do it it brings me to a folder like /exploded-ar/intermediates/ etc..

Comment: I still don't get you when you mean "change the size" ?!!!!

Comment: The drop down arrow in a spinner. Let's say it's currently 25x25 pixels. How and where do i change the size of it. I can simply put the background to be a new drawable of any size but was hoping i can use the stock supplied drop down arrow. I'll add a screen shot to what i need.

Comment: You can exploit the resource of stock android but cant actually change the size of it ! Cause its stock and its supposed to be the same size !

Comment: I wanted to set layout width and height of the drawable. But couldn't figure out where to do this, thought i could override the style but didn't work

Comment: You need to have a custom drawable to achieve what you want, you can accept only what's given in stock but cannot modify it. That's why they allow you to have a custom drawable as background !